# Removing tags from this `tag_names` attribute when then are removed form the input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Tag* model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

and a *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    return if @tag_names.blank?
    @tag_names.split(" ").each do |name|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      self.tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)
    end
  end
end
```

The `assign_tags` method stores the saved tags in `:tag_names` and displays it in an input field in this fashion: `tag1 tag2 tag3` (values are separated by spaces).

**views/posts/_form.html.erb:**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names %><br />  
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_names, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' '%>
  </div>
```

As you can see, `assign_tags`, enables me to add/push tags to `tag_names`. But if I delete a tag from the input field and save. The tag will still show up.

Any suggestions to help me solve this issue?

(Maybe `tag_names` should just empty itself before the tags are pushed in. But no idea how to code that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning tags, you'll want to clear the tags for that item. e.g.

```
def assign_tags
  self.tags = []
  return if @tag_names.blank?
  @tag_names.split(" ").each do |name|
    tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    self.tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)
  end
end
```

**Update:**

Or, a method that will hit the database a bit less:

```
def assign_tags
  ntags = []
  @tag_names.to_s.split(" ").each do |name|
    ntags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
  end
  self.tags = ntags
end
```

If you wanted to get really crazy with the write-less-do-more paradigm, you could do:

```
def assign_tags
  self.tags = @tag_names.to_s.split(" ").inject([]) do |arr, name|
    arr << Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    arr
  end
end
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend looking into the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm a little bit confused with the second code. I have to just replace this line: `self.tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)` with this line: `self.tags = @tag_names.to_s.split(" ")`?

Comment: or you are telling me to replace the whole method with just that line: `self.tags = @tag_names.to_s.split(" ")`?

Comment: No, the second code is just a cleaner implementation of the entire method.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it. I took that method I'm using from many tutorials. How come they didn't come out with that single line?

Comment: Sorry - actually I'm a bit wrong here... I'll update my response.